Simple convergence and boundedness in $L_{2}$ imply convergence in $L_{1}$.
Let $f_{n}, f \in L^{2}([a,b])$, such that $\lim f_{n} = f$ a.e on $[a,b]$. Let $$ \left\lVert f_n \right\rVert _{L^{2}} \leq M$$
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Show that lim $ \left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{1}} = 0$
How to proceed on this?

You probably mean $|f_n|_{L^2} \le M$ for all $n$?. Then use Egorov's theorem.

For $r>0$, By Ergorov theorem there is a measurable set $A\subset [a,b]$ such that $|[a,b]\setminus A|<r$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly on $A$
$$\left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{1}} = \left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{1}(A)} + \left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{1}([a,b]\setminus A)} \\\leq \left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{\infty}(A)} |A|+ |[a,b]\setminus A|^{1/2}\left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{2}}.$$
The boundedness of the sequence implies
$$\left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{1}} 
\leq \left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{\infty}(A)} |A|+ r^{1/2}C $$
Whence for all $r>0$,
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{1}} 
 \leq r^{1/2}C $$
that is letting $r\to0$ gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{1}} =0 $$

$\left\lVert f_{n} - f \right\rVert {L^{1}([a,b]\setminus A)} \leq |[a,b]\setminus A|^{1/2}\left\lVert f{n} - f \right\rVert _{L^{2}}$ Why is this true?

That is Cauchy Schwarz inequality applied to 1 and f_n-f

Sorry I donot understand, Cauchy Schwarz inequality on what norm, in the LHS, we have a L1-norm and on the RHS it is L2-norm. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Apply Cauchy inequality to the functions h=1 and g=f_n-f.
